# Validating Credit Card Numbers

Tags: java

i was doing a homework program in java and i got it to wok but had issues trying to make a while loop to make the program request for inputs till i type -1. i cant seem to get the program to keep asking for inputs, any help will be greatly appreciated and if you see any mistakes in my code please do tell me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Creditcard {
    // Return true if the card number is valid
    public static boolean isValid(long number) {

        int total = sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(number) + sumOfOddPlace(number);


        if ((total % 10 == 0) && (prefixMatched(number, 1) == true) && (getSize(number)>=13 )
                && (getSize(number)<=16 )) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int getDigit(int number) {

        if (number <= 9) {
            return number;
        } else {
            int firstDigit = number % 10;
            int secondDigit = (int) (number / 10);

            return firstDigit + secondDigit;
        }
    }
    public static int sumOfOddPlace(long number) {
        int result = 0;

        while (number > 0) {
            result += (int) (number % 10);
            number = number / 100;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static int sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(long number) {

        int result = 0;
        long temp = 0;

        while (number > 0) {
            temp = number % 100;
            result += getDigit((int) (temp / 10) * 2);
            number = number / 100;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static boolean prefixMatched(long number, int d) {

        String card; 
        if ((getPrefix(number, d) == 4) 
                || (getPrefix(number, d) == 5)
                || (getPrefix(number, d) == 6)
                || (getPrefix(number, d) == 37)) {

            if (getPrefix(number, d) == 4) {
                card = ("Visa ");
            } else if (getPrefix(number, d) == 5) {
                card = ("Master");
            } else if (getPrefix(number, d) == 6) {
                card = ("Discover Card ");
            } else if (getPrefix(number, d) == 37) {
                card = ("American Express cards");
            }

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }

    public static int getSize(long d) {

        int count = 0;

        while (d > 0) {
            d = d / 10;

            count++;
        }

        return count;

    }

    public static long getPrefix(long number, int k) {

        if (getSize(number) < k) {
            return number;
        } else {

            int size = (int) getSize(number);

            for (int i = 0; i < (size - k); i++) {
                number = number / 10;
            }

            return number;

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long number;
        // Create scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a credit card number: ");

        number=input.nextLong();
        if (isValid(number)) {
            String card;

        long n=getPrefix(number,1);

        if (n == 4)
            card = "Visa ";

        else if (n == 5)
            card = "Master ";

        else if (n == 6)
            card = "Discovery ";

        else
            card = "American Express ";

       System.out.print("This is a valid "+card+"Card Number");
    }
    else
    System.out.print("This is Invalid Credit Card Number");
    }
}
```

the problem i am having is i couldn't get it to repeatedly ask for credit cards till i press -1

```
Write a program named Creditcard.java that prompts the user for a credit card number and determines whether it is valid or not. (Much of this assignment is taken from exercise 6.31 in the book)

Credit card numbers follow certain patterns. A credit card number must have between 13 and 16 digits, and must start with:

4 for Visa cards
5 for Master cards
6 for Discover cards
37 for American Express cards
The algorithm for determining whether a card number is entered correctly as developed by Hans Luhn of IBM in 1954. The Luhn check or Mod 10 check works as follows. Consider the card number 5842016792622547.

Double every second digit from right to left. If the doubling of a digit results in a two-digit number, add up the digits to get a single-digit number. The digits are shown in bold and italic here:
5842016792622547

This gives us (from right to left):

4 * 2 = 8
2 * 2 = 4
6 * 2 = 12 → (1 + 2) = 3
9 * 2 = 18 → (1 + 8) = 9
6 * 2 = 12 → (1 + 2) = 3
0 * 2 = 0
4 * 2 = 8
5 * 2 = 10 → (1 + 0) = 1
Add up those numbers (8 + 4 + 3 + 9 + 3 + 0 + 8 + 1 = 36)
Now add up all the digits in the odd positions from right to left: (7 + 5 + 2 + 2 + 7 + 1 + 2 + 8 = 34)
Add those two numbers (36 + 34 = 70). If this sum is divisible by 10, the number is valid. If it is not divisible by 10, the number is not valid.
Your program will prompt the user to enter a credit card number as a long integer and display whether the number is valid or not. Design your program to use the following methods:

Return true if the card number is valid */
public static boolean isValid(long number)

Return the sum of the doubled even-place digits */
public static int sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(long number)

Return the given number if it is a single digit,
otherwise return the sum of the two digits */
public static int getDigit(int n)

Return the sum of the odd-place digits */
public static int sumOfOddPlace(long number)

Return the number of digits in the given number */
public static int getSize(long number)

Return the first length_prefix number of digits from number. If the number of digits in number is less than length_prefix, return number. */
public static long getPrefix(long number, int length_prefix)
You may also implement this function if you feel it is useful for your solution:

Return true if prefix is a prefix for number */
public static boolean prefixMatched(long number, int prefix)
Here is the result of running the program a few times:

Enter credit card number: 412345678
That is not a valid credit card number.
Enter credit card number: 5842016792428358
That is a valid credit card number.
Enter credit card number: 5782077482835719
That is not a valid credit card number.

Extra Challenges
Challenge 1: If the card is valid, display which type of card it is. For example:

Enter credit card number: 5842016792428358
That is a valid Master card number.
Challenge 2: Repeatedly ask for credit card numbers until the user enters -1. (Hint: while)
```

Comment: that is because you didn't write a loop in your main method. Since you have at least one loop in the rest of your code (that I've spotted so far), no doubt you'll figure out how to implement one

Comment: I don't see any attempt in your code to implement the *"repeatedly ask for credit cards till i press -1"* functionality.  Hint: when you want to repeatedly do something, use a loop!

Comment: i did it before and it made my output blank , i guess i didnt do it right. i will attempt it again.

Comment: Your main has simple if statement. If you want to get more inputs, use loop. Also use exit condition to terminate the program